# dp[!t][val] for skipping the parts from array

Tags: java, c++, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

consider the following snippet in cpp. This is taken from dynamic programming tutorial .

It is mainly for space optimized knapsack problem.

```
for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
{
    int t = a%2;
    for(int j=0;j<1100000;j++) dp[t][j]  = inf;
    for(int j=0;j<1100000;j++){
        dp[t][j] = min(dp[t][j],dp[!t][j-v[i-1]]+w[i-1]);//!t part is for skipping the current
    }
}
```

This snippet is taken from this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/yLM1F2LALA0?list=PL6i88TVbog4pQxY4K1jAYXjHf_uZDNGZ4&t=540).  I want to convert this technique into java. But java does not support this type of integer manipulation. Please can anyone explain me how it works and appropriate conversion to java ? thanks.

Comment: `dp[!t]` is not skipping a specific element. If `t` is `0` then `dp[!t]` is `dp[1]`, otherwise it is `dp[0]`. The only way it makes sense (assuming `dp` is an array and not some class time) is if `dp` is a `T[2]` array. Then, since `t` is always 0 or 1 here, `dp[t]` is either of those lines and `dp[!t]` is the other one.

Comment: What's wrong with 1-t?

Comment: If you want bitwise negation, you can use `~`

Comment: 1-t gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException you can check yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `!t` with `t ^ 1` or `1 - t` (whatever you find more readable; the effect is the same). That's all you need to do here.

### Explanation

Java supports all the integer manipulation on display in this snippet:

`int t = a % 2;` <-- this is valid java and means the same thing in java as it does in C: divide a by 2, and put the *remainder* in t, preserving the sign of `a`. Thus: `t` is now 0 if `a` was even, and `1` if a was positive and odd, and `-1` if a was negative and odd. It looks like `a` is supposed to be positive in this scenario, meaning that `t` can only be `0` or `1` here.

`dp[t][j]` <-- valid java. Declare `dp` as for example `int[][] dp = new int[100][100];`.

`min(someExpression, someOtherExpression)` <-- valid java; add `import static java.lang.Math.min;` or replace min with `Math.min` to make it work.

`dp[!t]` <-- the `!t` isn't valid java; but, in C, running `!t` where `t` is either 0 or 1 is just flipping things: If `t` is 1, `!t` is 0, and vice versa. And that you can trivially do in java: Use `t ^ 1` or `1 - t` or even `t == 0 ? 1 : 0` – all have the exact same behaviour and *are* valid java.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I specifically asked about the !t part. I tried both t^1 and 1-t in the !t. but It didn't work. It gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as it less than 0

Comment: @AashishPawar and I explained that part in this answer. If you're getting that error, either the code you pasted isn't the code you're running, or a is negative, in which case (as I said in my answer), t will be -1. The C code doesn't make a lot of sense there either. It probably acts as 't == 0 ? 1 : 0' in that case.